# enviar Email mediante NODEMAILER con React(ERROR 404)

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, nodemailer

Lado Cliente (Formulario)

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, {useState} from 'react';


const Contact = (e) => {
    const url = '/text-mail'
    const [Nombre, setNombre] = useState('');
    const [Asunto, setAsunto] = useState('');
    const [Email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [Message, setMessage] = useState('');

   const  SubmitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log({ Nombre,Asunto,Email,Message });
        Axios.post(url,{
            data: Nombre,Asunto,Email,Message,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                //handle success
                console.log(res.data);
            })   
   }
    return(
        <>
        <h1 className='flex justify-center text-3xl transform translate-y-28'>Private Contact</h1>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => SubmitForm(e)} className='transform translate-y-28' autoComplete='off'>
            <div className='FormCenter'>
                <input type='text' className='FormData' onChange={e => setNombre(e.target.value)}  name='Nombre' placeholder='Full Name' required/>
            </div>
            <div className='FormCenter'>
                <input type='text' className='FormData' onChange={e => setAsunto(e.target.value)}  name='Asunto' placeholder='Asunto' required/>
            </div>
            <div className='FormCenter'>
                <input type='text' className='FormData' onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}  name='Email' placeholder='Email@example.com' required/>
            </div>
            <div className='FormCenter'>
                <textarea className='h-32 FormData' onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}  name='Message' placeholder='Message' row='5' required/>
            </div>
            <div className='FormCenter'>
                <input type='submit' className='cursor-pointer Submit' name='Submit' value='Contact'/>
            </div>
        </form>
        </>
        )
    }

    
export default Contact;
```

express con Nodejs

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();
//importando 
require('dotenv/config');
// Parse incoming requests data (https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
const route = express.Router();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use('/v1', route);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});


const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    port: 587,
    host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
    auth: {
        user: 'narciso.hagenes52@ethereal.email',
        pass: 'S9Y5yYM6ZA5n4u2F2q',
    },
    
});

route.post('/text-mail', (req, res) => {
    const {Nombre,Asunto,Email,Message} = req.body;
    const mailData = {
        from: 'example@gmail.com',
        to: 'example@gmail.com',
        subject: 'enviado desde un formulario',
        text: 'Recibir' ,
        html: `<h1>Contact Details</h1>
            <p>Nombre:  ${Nombre}</p>
            <p>Asunto:  ${Asunto}</p>
            <p>Email:   ${Email}</p>
            <p>Message: ${Message}</p>
        
        `
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailData, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        res.status(200).send({ message: "Mail send", message_id: info.messageId });
    });
});
```

no entiendo en donde estoy fallando al hacer esto. me pueden orientar un poco en este caso nunca antes había usado Nodemailer. estoy intentando enviar un email a través de  un sencillo formulario. **De alguna forma antes de que axio pueda enviar los datos recibidos del formulario a backend me salta el error** ->
ERROR: **Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404**
arriba anexe el código del lado donde tengo el formulario y el server express

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generalmente, este error :

> ERROR: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code
> 404

se produce cuando la URL / ubicación proporcionada dentro del método POST no es correcta. Así que verifique la URL / ubicación nuevamente y corríjala.

Comment: dentro del metodo POST del **<form onSubmit={(e) => SubmitForm(e)} > </form>**  <- te refieres a esta parte de aqui?  o aparte de ello hay que ponerle un action='' ?

Comment: no, cuando da ese problema es porque probablemente no llegue ala ruta  del post/get/delete/update no es la correcta, pero si llega al endpoint entonces seria de revisarlo mas de serca

Comment: también puede ser por esto:

const route = express.Router();

y que tu endpoint sea asi route.post

en ves de eso ocupa app.post

Comment: corregí lo comentado. ahora me salió un error **net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR** ?

Comment: Esto creo q te puede ayudar con tu problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223253/how-do-i-update-nodemailer-to-use-https-ssl